# How to use debugger when simulating physics with SDL?

Tags: debugging, sdl, game-physics

I would like to use the debugger but I have two problems

1. I am using SDL to create a graphics window, when I run my program in Debug mode I can no longer see what is going on in the window.
2. When you are simulating physics the time elapsed affects the behaviour of the program but when you are debugging the time elapsed and the code are no longer in sync so the program cannot behave normally. What strategies can I use to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Redraw the window more frequently in the places that you want to debug, for example do one step code line to draw the line then next step line to redraw the window. Use 2 monitors so that debugger is in one and your program in the other. If you don't have 2 monitors then it will be a little inconvenient to debug but you can make your debugger window small and place it in one side of the screen and have your program running on the other side of the screen.
2. I must admit I don't know anything about simulating physics. If that's something where you use many threads and the order of execution matters between them then you can place breakpoints in each thread and then switching between threads you can step over and decide which thread and how far should progress. If that something within single thread then you may want to add a code which will be altering the time elapsed. Perhaps you could implement kind of simulator which would make sure the elapsed time in the given place of the code is as you would normally expect.